# Assigning variables in Makefile recipe

Tags: variables, makefile, gnu-make

In one of my Makefile recipes, I want to create a temporary file, pass the name of that file to a shell command and assign the output of that command to a make variable so that I can use that subsequently. For the life of me, I cannot get it to work.

For the purpose of debugging I have tried to boil down the problem to the most simple target I could come up with:

```
.PHONY: foo
foo:
    $(eval TMPFILE = $(shell mktemp -p ./))
    dd if=/dev/random of=${TMPFILE} bs=1 count=512
    $(eval FOO = $(shell wc -c ${TMPFILE}))
    @echo FOO: ${FOO}
```

Here is what happens:

```
❯ make foo
dd if=/dev/random of=./tmp.K1au4WrZ76 bs=1 count=512
512+0 records in
512+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 0.00287818 s, 178 kB/s
FOO: 0 ./tmp.K1au4WrZ76
```

So somehow, `wc` thinks the file is empty. But when I check the TMPFILE it has 512 bytes, as expected:

```
❯ wc -c tmp.K1au4WrZ76
512 tmp.K1au4WrZ76
```

Can someone, please enlighten me what is going on here and how to do that correctly?

Thanks
Phil

Update: Based on the answer I put together this target which works as desired:

```
.PHONEY: foo
.ONESHELL:
foo:
    set -e
    TMPFILE=`mktemp -p ./`
    dd if=/dev/random of=$$TMPFILE bs=1 count=512
    FOO=`wc -c $$TMPFILE`
    @echo FOO: $$FOO
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make always expands the entire recipe (all lines of the recipe) first, before it starts any shell commands.  So all your `eval`, etc. operations are invoked before any shell command, such as `dd`, is run.

Comment: Thanks – that explains a lot! So that means I would probably have to implement that purely on the shell side. Possibly using .ONESHELL for this target and using shell variables instead of make variables. But if I do it that way, the recipe would only fail if the last line fails – correct?

Comment: Yes, unless you wrote your shell commands to fail immediately.  You can do that by either writing command separated by `&&` instead of `;`, like `foo && bar && baz`, or by adding `set -e` to the beginning of your script.  Or add `|| exit 1` after each command.  Basically, it's nothing to do with make at this point: it's how you write your shell scripting.